# conditionally call vs. don't call a function using flax.linen

Tags: jax, flax

Based on a boolean flag, I want to either 1) call or 2) not call the following function (which operates on a flax linen module).

```
def true_fn(module, carry, inputs):

    carry, output = flax.linen.scan(function_to_scan_over, variable_broadcast = 'params', split_rngs = {"params": False})(module, carry, inputs)

    return carry
```

I have tried to use flax.linen.cond as follows

```
carry = flax.linen.cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, module, carry, inputs)
```

where false_fn is the identity function with respect to carry:

```
def false_fn(module, carry, inputs):

    return carry
```

But when I do this I get an error message saying

```
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: TypeError: true_fun and false_fun output must have same type structure
```

The output type structure is the same. I assume, based on the [flax.linen.cond documentation](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/flax.linen/_autosummary/flax.linen.cond.html), that I am getting the error message because true_fn creates variables that are not created in false_fn (this is a problem for flax.linen.cond but not jax.lax.cond). The module I am passing to true_fn always gets called later in my code, if that matters.

Any advice on what I should do here?

edit: MWE added:

```
from flax import linen as nn
import jax

class MLP(nn.Module):
    dim: int
    def setup(self):
        self.dense = nn.Dense(self.dim)
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.dense(x)

class Dummy(nn.Module):
    dim: int
    def setup(self):
        self.mlp = MLP(self.dim)
    def __call__(self, x):
        def true_fn(module, x):
            return module(x)
        def false_fn(module, x):
            return x
        y = nn.cond(True, true_fn, false_fn, self.mlp, x)
        return y + self.mlp(x)

dim_in = 3
dim_out = dim_in

dummy = Dummy(dim_in)
init_vars = dummy.init(x = jax.numpy.ones((dim_in,)), rngs = {'params': jax.random.PRNGKey(0)})
dummy.apply(init_vars, x = jax.numpy.ones((dim_in,)))
```

I am using flax 0.7.2 and jax/jaxlib 0.4.13.

Comment: Given the error, I suspect the output type structure is not actually the same. In particular, I'd look at whether any of the inputs are weakly typed, and whether the corresponding outputs are strongly typed. If this doesn't help, I'd suggest trying to construct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it's hard to debug code that I can't see!

Comment: I've added a MWE @jakevdp. Aside from getting this code to work, is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do more elegantly (the creation of an additional false_fn that effectively does nothing seems inelegant). For example, flax linen's while_loop only takes one function (which here would be true_fn), but I only want to call true_fn once, so invoking a loop also seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: If the condition is traced, `cond` is the way to do it. In your MWE the condition is static, so you could use a Python `if` statement if you wish, but I'm not sure if that aspect of the MWE reflects the characteristics of the real code. Your MWE makes pretty clear what the problem is, though: `true_fun` and `false_fun` return different pytree structures; to fix it you have to make them return the same pytree structure.

Comment: I don't understand why you say they return different pytree structures. As far as I can tell, they both return an array of the same size (in this example, the input to the linear neural network has the same dimensionality as the output). Can you explain why you say they return different pytree structures please.

Comment: When I run your MWE I see `TypeError: true_fun and false_fun output must have same type structure, got PyTreeDef((*, (({'params': {'dense': {'bias': *, 'kernel': *}}},),))) and PyTreeDef((*, (({},),))).` These are different structures: one has a `params` entry in the dict, and the other doesn't. This is why the two functions are not compatible with `cond`.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to offer a resolution to this error (using cond). I don't understand why the output structures are different given that the functions return an array of the same type and shape (I don't understand why true_fun is returning the parameters, for example).

Comment: It seems this is due to the "lifted" transformations that flax does in the background. I'm not sure how to fix your code.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can achieve my goal (of conditionally calling true_fn) by other means (e.g. not using cond, but still using flax linen operators as I get error messages in my original code if I mix Jax and Flax transformations) - as I mentioned above, it seems cumbersome to me to have to create a false_fn function that effectively does nothing.

Comment: It seems that one way to circumvent this issue is to call self.mlp once before calling nn.cond (e.g. during 'setup' or when self.mlp.is_mutable_collection('params') is True). That way, when nn.cond is called, true_fn does not try to return the parameters, as they have already been initialised, and so the output structures of true_fn and false_fn are the same. As mentioned before though, a solution that didn't require creating a redundant false_fn that performs an identity mapping (i.e. does nothing) would be preferable, if such a solution exists?